# What's wrong with my destructor?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, list, destructor

```
// Sparse Array Assignment.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.  
//  

#include "stdafx.h"  
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  
struct node{  
    int row;  
    int col;  
    int value;  
    node* next_in_row;  
    node* next_in_col;  
};  
class MultiLinkedListSparseArray {  
private:  
    char *logfile;  
    node** rowPtr;  
    node** colPtr; // used in constructor  
    node* find_node(node* out);  
    node* ins_node(node* ins,int col);  
    node* in_node(node* ins,node* z);  
    node* get(node* in,int row,int col);  
    bool exist(node* so,int row,int col);  
    node* dummy;  
    int rowd,cold;  
    //add anything you need  
public:  
    MultiLinkedListSparseArray(int rows, int cols);  
    ~MultiLinkedListSparseArray();  
    void setCell(int row, int col, int value);  
    int getCell(int row, int col);  
    void display();  
    void log(char *s);  
    void dump();  
};  
MultiLinkedListSparseArray::MultiLinkedListSparseArray(int rows,int cols){  
    rowPtr=new node* [rows+1];  
    colPtr=new node* [cols+1];  
    for(int n=0;n<=rows;n++)  
        rowPtr[n]=NULL;  
    for(int i=0;i<=cols;i++)  
        colPtr[i]=NULL;  
    rowd=rows;cold=cols;  
}  
MultiLinkedListSparseArray::~MultiLinkedListSparseArray(){  
    cout<<"array is deleted"<<endl;  
    for(int i=rowd;i>=0;i--){  
        for(int j=cold;j>=0;j--){  
            if(exist(rowPtr[i],i,j))  
                delete get(rowPtr[i],i,j);  
        }  
    }              // it stops in the last loop & doesnt show the done word
    cout<<"done"<<endl;  
    delete [] rowPtr;  
    delete [] colPtr;  
    delete dummy;  
}  
void MultiLinkedListSparseArray::log(char *s){  
    logfile=s;  
}  
void MultiLinkedListSparseArray::setCell(int row,int col,int value){  
    if(exist(rowPtr[row],row,col)){  
        (*get(rowPtr[row],row,col)).value=value;  
    }  
    else{  
        if(rowPtr[row]==NULL){  
            rowPtr[row]=new node;  
            (*rowPtr[row]).value=value;  
            (*rowPtr[row]).row=row;  
            (*rowPtr[row]).col=col;  
            (*rowPtr[row]).next_in_row=NULL;  
            (*rowPtr[row]).next_in_col=NULL;  
        }  
        else if((*find_node(rowPtr[row])).col<col){  
            node* out;  
            out=find_node(rowPtr[row]);  
            (*out).next_in_row=new node;  
            (*((*out).next_in_row)).col=col;  
            (*((*out).next_in_row)).row=row;  
            (*((*out).next_in_row)).value=value;  
            (*((*out).next_in_row)).next_in_row=NULL;  
        }  
        else if((*find_node(rowPtr[row])).col>col){  
            node* ins;  
            ins=in_node(rowPtr[row],ins_node(rowPtr[row],col));  
            node* g=(*ins).next_in_row;  
            (*ins).next_in_row=new node;  
            (*((*ins).next_in_row)).col=col;  
            (*(*ins).next_in_row).row=row;  
            (*(*ins).next_in_row).value=value;  
            (*(*ins).next_in_row).next_in_row=g;  
        }  
    }  
}  
int MultiLinkedListSparseArray::getCell(int row,int col){  
        return (*get(rowPtr[row],row,col)).value;  

}  
void MultiLinkedListSparseArray::display(){  
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
        for(int j=1;j<=5;j++){  
            if(exist(rowPtr[i],i,j))  
                cout<<(*get(rowPtr[i],i,j)).value<<" ";  
            else cout<<"0"<<" ";  
        }  
        cout<<endl;  
    }  
}  
node* MultiLinkedListSparseArray::find_node(node* out)  
{  
    while((*out).next_in_row!=NULL)  
        out=(*out).next_in_row;  
    return out;  
}  
node* MultiLinkedListSparseArray::ins_node(node* ins,int col){  
    while(!((*ins).col>col))  
        ins=(*ins).next_in_row;  
    return ins;  
}  
node* MultiLinkedListSparseArray::in_node(node* ins,node* z){  
    while((*ins).next_in_row!=z)  
        ins=(*ins).next_in_col;  
    return ins;  
}  
node* MultiLinkedListSparseArray::get(node* in,int row,int col){  
    dummy=new node;  
    dummy->value=0;  
    while((*in).col!=col){  
        if((*in).next_in_row==NULL){  
            return dummy;  
        }  
        in=(*in).next_in_row;  
    }  
    return in;  
}  
bool MultiLinkedListSparseArray::exist(node* so,int row,int col){  
    if(so==NULL)  
        return false;  
    else{  
    while((*so).col!=col){  
        if((*so).next_in_row==NULL)  
            return false;  
        else  
            so=(*so).next_in_row;  
    }  
    return true;  
    }  
}    
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MultiLinkedListSparseArray a(5, 5);
a.setCell(1, 5, 4);
a.setCell(2, 1, 2);
a.setCell(2, 2, 3);
a.setCell(3, 4, 5);
a.setCell(4, 1, 7);
a.setCell(4, 5, 8);
a.setCell(5, 2, 6);
cout << "X[4, 1] = " << a.getCell(4, 1) << endl;
cout << "X[4, 5] = " << a.getCell(4, 5) << endl;
cout << "X[2, 2] = " << a.getCell(2, 2) << endl;
cout << "X[5, 1] = " << a.getCell(5, 1) << endl;
a.display();
a.setCell(3, 4, 0);
a.setCell(1, 5, 0);
cout<<a.getCell(1,5)<<endl;
a.setCell(2, 2, 0);
a.setCell(5, 2, 0);
a.setCell(4, 5, 0);
//a.setCell(2, 5, 7); // problem WHY????????!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
a.setCell(5, 3, 8);
a.setCell(2, 3, 5);
a.setCell(2, 5, 3);
a.setCell(2, 1, 0);
a.setCell(4, 2, 4);
a.setCell(4, 2, 2);
a.setCell(4, 2, 0);
a.setCell(4, 1, 0);
a.setCell(2, 3, 0);
a.setCell(2, 5, 0);
a.setCell(5, 3, 0);
a.display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try indenting the code by 4 spaces, that will make it at least somewhat readable. Next, try asking a question instead of just copying all your code and hoping for the best, good information to include would be what happens now and what you expect to happen when the code is correct.

Comment: a) Please properly format your code next time. b) Just dumping this amount of code here and then asking "What's wrong with it?" is a sure way not to get help. Put a little effort into your question, please.

Comment: Sparse Array Assignment.cpp ??? homework? If so, please mark as such...

Comment: This is a 'Plz send de codz' question (IMHO), and therefore can be closed.

Comment: I'm not asking about the whole code it works alright it's just the destructor get stuck in the for loop & doesnt continue running the program Sorry about that long code but I just wanted you to see the new pointer created to see what's wrong. And sorry I didnt know about code indenting it's my second question here

Comment: Your code DOESN'T work if it fails on it's destructor. Failing destructor usually means problem with dynamic memory allocation and, well, all these pointers and `new` and `delete` are pretty tough to get used to...

Comment: @Ahmed Sharara : You should add your "main" function, where the "sparse array" is tested. Because we won't reproduce the same bug as you did without the same tests. Note that Kotti already discovered one bug, and advised you to rethink your whole object, so...

Comment: I added my main function

Comment: if I just delete the for loop in the destructor it works well but pointers wont be deleted .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things obviously go wrong, because `get` method (which, as I assume should be marked as `const`) makes memory allocation. I don't get the reason why this should be done and you should think about it.

So, your `get` methods allocates memory for `dummy` every time it is called (this is a leak). But, what is even worse, if sequence of user actions with your class doesn't have one or more calls to `get`, your dummy remains simply an uninitialized pointer. Then, when you call your destructor, you will get an error, because you can't dispose memory pointed by a garbage pointer.

Try to rethink, refactor or even rewrite your code.

Comment: the problem isnot in the dummy it stops before even getting to the deleting the dummy pointer so the problem is in the loop. but thank you for you answer I'll consider rewriting my code

Comment: Not sure about your real code, but you wrote about destructor problem and my test code was `MultiLinkedListSparseArray m(25, 25);`. And, hell yeah, it fails on attempt to delete your `dummy`...

Comment: but , it doesnt fail before reaching the dummy node ??? on my compiler it fails to delete the nodes created (the for loop inside the destructor)

Comment: See the previous comment. I didn't even try to do something more useful with your class except creating it and destructing. But I'm pretty sure that if it fails in the loop when you're trying to dispose elements, it's all about memory management. You could try to debug your code line-by-line and find the places where code behaviour differs from what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: It's all about effort, actually :)